# position Shapes on a canvas in JavaFX

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I create Shape and I need to position on a Canvas

`Class Square` to draw a square and insert into a `canvas` position

```
public class Square{
    //calculate the position of the rand column to 
    //draw and insert in the position of the canvas
    public void drawSquare(int posX, int posY, GraphicsContext gc) {
        //Square Shadow 
        //gc.rect(posX, posY, w, h);
        gc.rect(posX + 1, posY + 53, 50, 50);
        gc.fill();
        gc.beginPath();
        //Square
        gc.beginPath();
        gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.setLineWidth(2);
        //gc.rect(posX, posY, w, h);
        gc.rect(posX + 1, posY + 53, 48, 48);
        gc.fill();
        gc.stroke();

    }
}
```

New `Canvas instance` with `height = 450` and `width = 600`

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.setHeight(450);
canvas.setWidth(600);
```

and `GraphicsContext` to `draw square`

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
```

with this loop, draw 4 `rows` and 6 `columns` with `square` in `canvas`,
and my doubt is how to `calculate the position` of the `line` and `column` to `draw square` and insert in the `position` of the canvas when I call `pieces.drawSquare(i, j, gc);`, and method `drawSquare` creates the shape but the doubt is how to `position` them if it is more than one shape

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //4 rows
      for (int j = 0; j < 6; i++) { //6 columns
        Piece pieces = new Piece();
        pieces.drawSquare(i, j, gc);
      }
```

this image is the example,

[image]

and the objective is to fill in 4 rows and 6 columns

[image]

I have already thought about dividing the size and width of Canvas with the size and width of the shape but it is not working, maybe can have another solution

Comment: I could not read everything, but what I understand is that you want to fill your canvas with rectangles, except the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can get you jump starting

[image]

```
public class Main extends Application {

private SimpleIntegerProperty rowProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(4); //default
private SimpleIntegerProperty columnProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(6);//default


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        HBox top;
        TextField rowField = new TextField();
        rowField.setMaxWidth(60);
        rowField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                    String oldValue, String newValue) {
                try{ rowProperty.setValue(Integer.valueOf(newValue));}catch(NumberFormatException e){}
            }
        });
        TextField colField = new TextField();
        colField.setMaxWidth(60);
        colField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                    String oldValue, String newValue) {
                try{ columnProperty.setValue(Integer.valueOf(newValue));}catch(NumberFormatException e){}
            }
        });
        top = new HBox(10,new Label("ROW FIELD"),rowField, new Label("COLUMN FIELD"),colField);
        top.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
        root.setTop(top);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500,400);
        canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setStroke(Color.GOLD);

        ChangeListener<Number> chan = new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            int space = 2;
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                    Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                ///i will draw here
                canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                int rectW = (int) canvas.getWidth();
                rectW = rectW/columnProperty.intValue();
                int rectH = (int) canvas.getHeight();
                rectH = rectH/rowProperty.intValue();

                System.out.println(rectW);
                System.out.println(rectH);

                for(int k = 0; k < canvas.getHeight()/rectH; k++){
                    for(int i =0; i< canvas.getWidth()/rectW; i++){
                        canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect((i*rectW) + (i*space),
                                (k*rectH) + (k*space),
                                rectW, rectH);
                    }
                }

            }
        };
        rowProperty.addListener(chan);
        columnProperty.addListener(chan);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        root.setCenter(canvas);
        Label l = new Label("ENTER NUMBERS TO FIELDS TO SEE IT");
        l.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blueviolet; -fx-text-fill: white;");
        l.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        l.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setBottom(l);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: thank Elltz, that was it, the goal is to get to this operation `canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect((i*rectW) + (i*space), (k*rectH) + (k*space), rectW, rectH);` with `canvas.getHeight()/rectH` and `canvas.getWidth()/rectW`